# How to add padding to right hand side of plot, equal to distance between left edge and left axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the output of a saved figure, with two side-by-side subplots, to have an equal looking spacing on the left and right of the plots, so that when the figure is included in a document, it looks like the plots are collectively centred.

[image]

In other words, add padding of width 'a' from the figure to the right hand side of the figure.

Here is some sample code (with the data replaced):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x1 = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0)
x2 = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0)
y1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x1) * np.exp(-x1)
y2 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x2)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,
                         ncols=2,
                         dpi=220,
                         squeeze=False,
                         figsize=(3.45, 2.1)
)

axes[0][0].plot(x1, y1, 'o-')
axes[0][0].set_ylabel('Damped oscillation')
axes[0][0].set_xlabel('time (s)')
axes[0][1].plot(x2, y2, '.-')
axes[0][1].set_xlabel('time (s)')

for i in [0, 1]:
    x0, x1 = axes[0][i].get_xlim()
    x_diff = x1 - x0
    y0, y1 = axes[0][i].get_ylim()
    y_diff = y1 - y0
    axes[0][i].set_aspect(x_diff / y_diff)
    axes[0][i].tick_params(labelbottom='off', labelleft='off', axis=u'both', which=u'both', length=0)
    axes[0][i].xaxis.labelpad = 7
    axes[0][i].yaxis.labelpad = 7

fig.savefig('clustering.pdf',
            bbox_inches='tight',
            pad_inches=0,
            dpi='figure')
```

Comment: Don't use `bbox_inches="tight"` if you don't like the automatic cropping. Instead adjust the subplot parameters to your liking via `fig.subplots_adjust()`.

Comment: Hey @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I tried fig.subplots_adjust(), but still couldn't get what I wanted. Any advice?

Comment: Na, that needs to work.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, yup, got it figured out. Had to set left = 1-right in plt.subplots_adjust. Any idea how you could do it automatically, without needing to trial and error?

Comment: `left` needs to be *smaller*  than `right`. You could call `tight_layout` obtain the `left` parameter from it and then set `right` to `1-left`.